# Get edited data of OData Binding

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

Does anyone know the best approach of getting the changed data of an odata model property after binding it to a form / set of input controls via [bindElement](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement)?

Currently I am doing something like `this.getView().bindElement('/SomeEntitySet(0815)');`. But I struggle with getting back the edited data from my view. The only methods the binding is offering to me is getting back the odata model itself, which contains the original, non edited data. 
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the odataModel there's an Property called refreshAfterChange this should be set to true by default.

Are you sure your changes applies to your backend data? The oDataModel from sapui5 should update the binding by itself([checkout: mParameters.refreshAfterChange](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#constructor)).
If the Change method work debug your oData service and check if the change method trigger a GET request to your backend(The odatamodel should trigger a get request if the data has been changed => see refreshAfterChange in link above, the refresh of the model will do a GET request like it does if you bind data to an element). If not theres something wrong with your model confoiguration.

Could you add the code where and how you initiate the model?